# Where's a good place to play D&D online?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons

I'm a beginner, but I've played other RPGs before.  I travel a lot so I can't really dedicate myself to a local group.  Are there places to play campaigns online?
Is this even feasible?

Edit: To be more clear, I am looking for groups that play online via email or something like that.

Comment: Do you care about what edition you play?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - I am looking specifically for groups that play online.  Maybe there is a website for this sort of thing, for example.

Comment: Online and in-person are both covered in the answers there. What I'm unsure of is whether we need two questions, one for in-person and one for online. Possibly, possibly not, so we'll see how the voting on the possible duplicate turns out.

Comment: I've opened a [meta question on whether this is a duplicate of our canonical question](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5323/does-our-canonical-where-can-i-find-other-rpg-players-question-serve-online-pl) that I hope interested parties will weigh in on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been playing campaigns in [Roll20](http://roll20.net) for two years now and it works pretty well for me. It's mostly system-agnostic. Their [2014 report](http://blog.roll20.net/post/107957194710/the-orr-group-industry-report-q4-2014) shows that the most popular systems are D&D/Pathfinder (PF, 5E, 3.5, 4E, AD&D, OD&D in that order), Star Wars, Dark Heresy, Shadowrun, GURPS, Dungeon World, FATE, etc.